# Focusing Input Field With Keypress Adds a Character

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to focus an input field element whenever the user presses the '/' key. However, once the element is focused, it also adds the '/' key to the input field because it types in the '/' from when I was trying to detect it.

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("formInput")
  if (event.key == '/') {
    element.focus()
    element.value = element.value.slice(0, -1)
  }
})
```

I tried slicing the value afterwards but it turns out, the value in the input field doesn't update until it goes out of the function from the event listener.

How would I remove the extra '/' from the input field *after* the '/' shows up in the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preventDefault` method to prevent the default behavior of the key press, which in this case is adding the '/' character to the input field:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "/") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("formInput").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="formInput" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked. I'll accept this as the answer once StackOverflow allows it